# how to print the json data into textview

Tags: android, json

In my app i am trying to access the api through JSON to convert the amount from one currency to another by using an [api](http://farebookings.blogspot.in/2013/11/currency-conversion-util.html) and used the below snippet.
But `onClick` is not returning anything and also not giving any error!
what am i doing wrong?
please help.

```
private static final String API_URL = "http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/t1.toString()/t2.toString()/1/json";// PUT

                public String t1="";                                                                                                                    

                public String t2="";    

btnDoit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!usdValue.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                    client.get(API_URL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String response) {
                            Log.i("CHACHING", "HTTP Sucess");

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONObject ratesObject = jsonObj
                                        .getJSONObject("data");

                                Double RateFrom = ratesObject.getDouble("t1.toString()");
                                Double RateTo = ratesObject.getDouble("t2.toString()");


                                Double usds = Double.valueOf(usdValue.getText()
                                        .toString());

                                Double gbps = usds * RateFrom;
                                Double euros = usds * RateTo;
                                Result.setText("ConvertedFrom: "
                                        + String.valueOf(gbps)+ "ConvertedTo: "
                                                + String.valueOf(euros));
                                //ConvertedTo.setText("ConvertedTo: "
                                        //+ String.valueOf(RateTo));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter a Amount value!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {


        codey = ConvertedFromCurr.getSelectedItem().toString();
        codey1 = ConvertedToCurr.getSelectedItem().toString();

        code = codey.split("\\s+");

        for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {


   t1= code[1].toString();
   Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),t1.toString(),
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Code.append("" + code[1].toString() + "")     

}


        code1 = codey1.split("\\s+");

        for (int i = 0; i < code1.length; i++) 
        {


   t2= code1[1].toString();
   Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), t2.toString(),
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Code.append("" + code[1].toString() + "");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/t1.toString()/t2.toString()/1/json](http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/t1.toString%28%29/t2.toString%28%29/1/json) is invalid URL. Though you should get JSON exception. However, if you change url to valid one, you still don't get "data" object in JSON response. Lastly, it's possible that logcat simply crashed.

Comment: @ user1889459 can you tell me how to pass valid url.? t1 t2 are the currency selected by user that he want to change..that i extract from dropdown list..??
i think,i am doing wrong json access

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
 
 //String t1 = etFrom.getText().toString();//from EditText
 int t1Index = myDropDownList.getSelectedIndex();//It should have method similar to this
 String t1 = myBackingList.get(t1Index);//get selected item from the backing list
 String t2 = ...//repeat
 int amount = Integer.parseInt(etAmount.getText().toString());
 String url = "http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/"+t1+"/"+t2+"/"+amount+"/json";
 ...
}

Comment: @  user1889459 thank you..but have 1 more doubt how can i see the complete json format of this api

Comment: Log.d(TAG,jsonObj.toString(2));